# Mesh has more materials than subsets Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Getting this error on my computer with Unity 5.5.1f1 Personal 64 bit. Its a asset package that is imported. The same package works on other computers with same version. Even if it was exported from my computer. But wont work on my computer.

Comment: Sounds like an error during import. Recommend that you check the editor log and/or inspect the imported assets for anything that stands out. Any errors in the log? Any extra or missing asset data?

Comment: Make sure you also have the *.meta files associated with that package in place, inside the folder.